# how to add an outside value with a database value in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

In android studio, I want to take a value from an edit text and put it in database, when I enter another value from the edit text it will add that to the first one. like if i put 50, then i put 25, in the database it will contain 75

i am using this code to update the values in the database

```
    public boolean addvalue(long rowId, String newAmt) {
    String where = "KEY_ROWID" + "=" + rowid;

    SQLiteDatabase db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_PROG, newAmt);

     return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) !=0;
}
```

when i try to run, the update does apply and it simply replaces the former with the latter, i am still new to android studio and sqlite please help

Comment: "KEY_ROWID" to KEY_ROWID. Because "KEY_ROWID" consider as fieldName

Answer (score 0):

`ContentValues` objects handle only plain values.

To be able to do computations, you have to use [execSQL()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[])) instead:

```java
db.execSQL("UPDATE "+DATABASE_TABLE+
           " SET "+KEY_PROG+"="+KEY_PROG+"+?"+
           " WHERE "+KEY_ROWID+"=?",
           new Object[]{ newAmt, rowId });
```

`execSQL()` does not return anything, so if you really need the number of updated rows, you have to use a separate [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])):

```java
return DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT changes()", null) > 0;
```

Comment: I tried applying your code but it seems to show an error

in here "+?" and in here "=?"

Comment: Thank you very much for keeping the error messages secret.